# Regex to find and remove single line comments from SQL in Python

Tags: python, regex

This might have been answered before but I have some scenarios where valid lines are captured as comment for which I could not find any results

My code:

```
rgxcomment = re.compile(r"(--[^\r\n]*)",re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE) 
x = rgxcomment.findall(item)
        if len(x)>0:
            item = item.replace(';','')
            for j in x:
                index = item.find(j)
                item = item[:index] + '' + item[index+len(j):]
```

My SQL:

```
    CREATE  TESTING.TABLENAME AS
    SELECT
    a.TYPE, -- type 
    '--' AS BLANK,
    a.ID,
    --a.MONTH,
   a.DAY
    from tablea a
```

Here my comments are only  -- type in 3rd line and --a.MONTH in 6th line in the SQL. However My code is capturing the 4th line as well and removing that too

Expected result:

```
    CREATE  TESTING.TABLENAME AS
    SELECT
    a.TYPE,
    '--' AS BLANK,
    a.ID,
   a.DAY
    from tablea a
```

Actual Result

```
CREATE  TESTING.TABLENAME AS
        SELECT
        a.TYPE,
        '
        a.ID,
       a.DAY
        from tablea a
```

This is giving invalid SQL.

I would like to modify my pattern so that if "--" is enclosed inside a single or double quotes such as " -- " or '--' this should be captured as comment

Comment: Not quite what you asked for but does `(^\s*--[^\r\n]*)` do what you need?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### If your comment starts at the beginning of the line

You can add `^` to make your regex start at the beginning of the line, and add `[ ]*` for it to accept an unknown number of spaces before it.

Your regex would then be `^[ ]*(--[^\r\n]*)`.

With your SQL example and this regex, only the line 6 is captured.

### If you just want to catch the comment when `--` is not between quotes

Then you would just need to add the quotes as an excluding match by adding `[^'"]`: `([^'"]--[^'"][^\r\n]*)`.

In your example, that matches the 6th line (but not the spaces at the beginning of it) and also `-- type` in the 3rd line.

You could also add the spaces in case you want to catch the entire line if it all is a comment:
`([ ]*[^'"]--[^'"][^\r\n]*)`

Comment: I would have to capture even if comment starts in between the line. Have to ignore only if -- are enclosed by quotes

Will update the question to clarify better, Thanks for the response

Comment: I have edited my answer then. Does that address your issue?